# Best way to implement save and restore object attribute state

Tags: java, android, serialization

What is the best way to implement save and restore / push and pop object attribute state? Like glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix()?

For example:

```
obj.v1 = false;
obj.v2 = 0;
obj.v3 = "init";

obj.save();
obj.v1 = true;
obj.v2 = 2;
obj.v3 = "foo"
/* Do something... */

obj.restore();
/* Now v1 = false, v2 = 0, v3 = "init" again */
```

Answer (score 2):

**To save to a file: Make your class serializable**

```
package com.yourpackage.name;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class myClass implements Serializable {
    public enum counterType {
        count_down,
        count_up
    }
    public int myIntValue= 0;
}
```

If you get the warning 'The Serializable class X does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long', you can solve this by adding a value for serialVersionUID, e.g.:

`private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890abcdefg;`

Declare your variable as you always do (e.g. in your main activity):

```
myClass myClassVariable = new myClass();
myClassVariable.myIntValue = 99;
```

Now you can save the data to a file, using:

```
try
{
   FileOutputStream myFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "file_name.ser");
   ObjectOutputStream myObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(myFileOutputStream);
   myObjectOutputStream.writeObject(myClassVariable);
   myObjectOutputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Error when saving to file.",Log.getStackTraceString(e)); 
}
```

To load your data again:

```
try
{
    FileInputStream myFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "file_name.ser");
    ObjectInputStream myObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(myFileInputStream);
    readClassVariable = (myClass) myObjectInputStream.readObject(); 
    myObjectInputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Error when loading from file.",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

readClassVariable now contains your saved class, e.g. readClassVariable.myIntValue is equal to 99

Hope it helps. Comments welcome :)

*P.S. I need the rep, so don't forget to accept answer if you like it!*

Comment: Is it necessarily output to a file? Can it be all done in RAM?

Comment: Is it possible to use ByteArrayOutputStream instead of FileOutputStream?

Answer (score -1):

**To save to RAM:**

You can simply copy it to another class variable.

However note that when you use the equal sign only the REFERENCE is copied (you are still working with the same variable):

`myClass1 = myClass2`

In this case, the easiest is to make a new class and copy the parameters individually for all parameters:

```
myClass1.myIntValue = myClass2.myIntValue
```

This way you copy the **value** and not a **reference** to the (same) variable.

Comment: Would serialize have better performance or space-friendly? As push and pop is not about making one backup copy.

Comment: For saving to a file yes, serialize is the most efficient way. If you do not want to save to a file, simply use a (local) variable to temp. store the value...