# How to generate auto increment ID and do not set to default when a program is closed and opened again in java?

Tags: java

I am generating the auto increment number as the code below.

```
public class CoachRegForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form CoachRegForm
 */
   private static int counter = 10000;
    final private int coachId;



public CoachRegForm() {
    initComponents();
     coachId = counter++;
     String staffIDInString=new Integer(coachId).toString();
     CoachRegFormIDShowLab.setText(staffIDInString);      
}
```

It works within the system, but when I close the program and run again, it goes back to the default which is 10000.

Is there any method to carry the last number saved by the program to the next time I open the program?

Comment: you need to persist this counter somewhere, otherwise it will be lost after you close the program, it is temporarily stored in the memory and cleared out after you close the program

Comment: yes you need to store it some where as @Simon pointed out , if you have db persist over there or you can make use of file systems to update the counter in a properties file again and again

Comment: you can use java serialization e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251006/best-way-to-implement-save-and-restore-object-attribute-state

Answer (score 1):

Your `static` `counter` field exists in the memory until your JVM shuts down (i.e., program end for standalone `main()` applications), so if you wanted to save and retrieve the `counter` value again, **you need a persistent store like a database** (preferable) or file system.

You can use Java API to connect to database (`java.sql.*` i.e., JDBC) to connect to database or file system API (i.e., `java.io.*`) &

Answer (score 0):

A good way to store some field value is Preferences: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html
You might also consider using an AtomicInteger to prevent problems with concurrency (within *ONE* multithreaded instance of your program) in future.

```
package preferences;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PrefsAutoinc {
    private Preferences prefs;
    private static final String AI_SETTING_ID = "autoincrement";

    public void testPrefs() {
        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());

        AtomicInteger autoinc = new AtomicInteger(prefs.getInt(AI_SETTING_ID, 0));

        System.out.println("last saved value: " + autoinc);

        System.out.println("next: " + autoinc.incrementAndGet());
        System.out.println("next: " + autoinc.incrementAndGet());

        prefs.putInt(AI_SETTING_ID, autoinc.get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrefsAutoinc test = new PrefsAutoinc();
        test.testPrefs();
    }
}
```

Of course if your program uses a database in any other way, then storing autoincrement value in database would be a better choice, as @javaguy suggests.

However, if you plan to run multiple instances of your application at the same time and the uniqueness of id is a must, then using centralized db storage is the only choice. Because each instance would increment it's own copy of variable and then save it in preferences, some values would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in an ini file. You will need to update the value each time it changes.

If you do not want the users to easily detect the value, then you can store it in a database.

Anyway, you will need to not initialize it to 10000, just in the case the value was not already saved somewhere.